# calling job from another job it's failing with Unable to load the job: please specify the name and repository directory OR a filename in pdi

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

but i have given enitre repositry path along with job name but that .kjb is not given
ERROR (version 9.3.0.0-428, build 9.3.0.0-428 from 2022-04-12 04.56.25 by buildguy) :
Error running job entry 'job' :
ERROR (version 9.3.0.0-428, build 9.3.0.0-428 from 2022-04-12 04.56.25 by buildguy) :
org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException:
Unable to load the job: please specify the name and repository directory OR a filename

```
at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.job.JobEntryJob.execute(JobEntryJob.java:701)
at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:703)
at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:844)
at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:844)
at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:844)
at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:844)
at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:513)
at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.run(Job.java:393)
```

Answer (score 1):

In PDI you're either connected to a repository or working directly from the filesystem.

A) If you're connected to a repository you must specify the repository directory AND job name.

B) If you work directly from the filesystem you must specify the full path and filename.

You can't do both at the same time. It's either option A or option B.

Comment: Repository is given along with job name but that extension .kjb is required to add in pentaho 9.3 version?

Comment: Job name doesn’t include extension.